# Using results of two SUM calculation in same query for a percentage

Tags: postgresql, calculation

There are analogous question but nothing usefull for me.

I need to obtain a unique table as a selection, where I can find 3 calculated fields, two SUM and then I need to calculate the percentage of them. How can I do it?

```
SELECT
pro_com,
(SUM(presence) FILTER(WHERE date_block = '2016-10-09 03:00:00')::integer AS date1,
(SUM(presence) FILTER(WHERE date_block = '2016-10-16 03:00:00')::integer AS date2,
(date1/date2*100)::integer AS percentage
FROM tab_presence
GROUP BY pro_com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may nest the dates and calculate percentage outside the parentheses.

```
SELECT 
       pro_com, 
       date1, 
       date2, 
       ( date1 / date2 * 100 )::INTEGER AS percentage 
FROM   
 ( 
SELECT   
  pro_com, 
   SUM(presence) FILTER(WHERE date_block = '2016-10-09 03:00:00')::INTEGER AS date1, 
   SUM(presence) FILTER(WHERE date_block = '2016-10-16 03:00:00')::INTEGER AS date2     
  FROM  tab_presence 
 GROUP BY pro_com 
   ) s
```